# Using compare validator

Tags: asp.net

Is there a way in using compare validator that when you use lessthanequal or greaterthanequal operator it automatically treat the type as int? Let's say adding additional tag in web config or any setup? thanks

Answer (score 0):

[CompareValidator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.comparevalidator.aspx) has a [Type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.basecomparevalidator.type.aspx) property that you could use.

```
<asp:CompareValidator ID="CV_GreaterTen" 
   Type="Integer" 
   Operator="GreaterThanEqual" 
   ValueToCompare="10" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Must be at least 10" ControlToValidate="Textbox1">*
</asp:CompareValidator>
```

Apart from that, there is no automatism.

By the way, such magical(mostly hidden) settings would be a good source for future problems.

Comment: Thanks..I ask because what if the type was overlook and the developer should compare integers?...

Comment: @dax: Please describe better what you mean.